# regardin (GDB) finding the value of a variable

Tags: c++

i am new to programming, and i have this problem regarding using the (gdb).
so i have this code which is completely correct:

```
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std; 

 bool is_equal(char *str1, char *str2){ 
 int i;
  for( i=0; str1[i]!='\0' && str2[i]!='\0'; i++)    
    if(str1[i]!=str2[i])    
     return false;   

    if(str1[i]!='\0' || str2[i]!='\0')   
    return false;

   return true;
 }

   int main(int argc, char *argv[]) { 
    if(argc >= 3)    
       cout << is_equal(argv[1], argv[2]) << endl;  

    return 0;
 }
```

NEW CODE :

```
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std; 

 bool is_equal(char **str1, char **str2){
// i have added (*) on each parameter 
 int i;
   for( i=0; str1[i]!='\0' && str2[i]!='\0'; i++)    
      if(str1[i]!=str2[i])    
         return false;   

  if(str1[i]!='\0' || str2[i]!='\0')   
      return false;

   return true;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) { 
   if(argc >= 3)    
      cout << is_equal(&argv[1], &argv[2]) << endl; 
// i have added (&) on both argvs. 

   return 0;
}
```

so when i try to use the gdb to find out the values of str1 and str2 it gives me a message saying that " No symbol "str1" in current context. "
and when i try to use my breakpoint on the function it gives me " rogram exited normally."

i know that the question may seem dumb, but can you please guide me?

Comment: "so i have this code which is completely correct:" :-)

Comment: Make sure you compile with optimisation disabled and debug symbols enabled, i.e. `gcc -Wall -O0 -g ...`

Comment: and i suspect that the second code doesnt compile - you cant just add a level of indirection on the function params, you need an extra dereference on use

Comment: regarding the second code: the point of putting * and & is to find the logic error through GDB but i couldn't i do not know